# Prove that the probabilty of a certain event is either zero or one.

Tags: probability

Let $(A_n)$ be events in $\mathcal F$ and let $\mathcal A$ be the smallest $\sigma$-filed containing each of these events. If $B$ is an event in $\mathcal A$ with the property that, for any integers $i_1,...,i_k$ the events $B$ and $A_{i_1} \cap...\cap A_{i_k}$ are independent, prove that $P(B)$ is either $0$ or $1$.

I think it may need using 0-1 law. But I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no need of such a strong weapon. This is much simpler... At least if it is assumed that we have a finite collection of sets. But saying that "Let $(A_n)$ be events in $\mathcal F$..." sort of implies that we have that.

Consider the following figure depicting some sets and all the "atoms". These sets and their arbitrary intersections can be formed by a union of the atoms.

[image]

For instance $A_2\cap A_3$ is the union of the black atom, the purple atom, and the white atom.

Note that any intersection of the sets equal a union of some atoms. Also, note that $B$ is, again, a union of some atoms.

The OP's statement says that if a sum of some atoms is independent from all the unions of the atoms then the probability of the former union is ether zero or one.

Considering that $B$ is a union of atoms then the statement above claims that $B$ is independent from itself... So???

Comment: Still a formal proof is not that easy, unless the family of sets $(A_n)$ is finite.

My strategy would be to approximate $B$ by some $C$ (of which it is independent) such that $P(B \Delta C) < \epsilon$, and then to work with $P(B) \approx P(B \cap C) = P(B) P(C) \approx P(B)^2$. 

But how to construct the correct algebra which includes $C$ does not seem to be entirely obvious.

Comment: @MathiasVetter: I edited my answer and explicitly assumed finiteness. The OP will tell if this is the case. If not then they will have to be more specific. --Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Your solution means B is a union of 'atoms' and each 'atoms' are independent of B right?

Comment: No. My only assumption is that there are are only a finite number of $A$s. As a consequence: All the intersections are unions of atoms. In the sigma algebra all the unions of atoms are contained. $B$ is a union of atoms. This is way $B$ has to be independent from itself.

Comment: I don't understand 'The OP's statement says that if a sum of some atoms is independent from all the unions of the atoms' What is OP's statement?

Comment: @smart Lee: B is independent of all unions of atoms. B is a union of some atoms...